# The Ubuntu GNOME installer starts, but I can't see my mouse

Tags: gnome, cursor, ubuntu-gnome

Just had a question yesterday. On a roll.

Anyway.

I started the Ubuntu GNOME installer and no mouse appears. The OS (might be!) is frozen. 
The thing is, when it boots up, I see the mouse for a split second and then it disappears. 
This happens in every vanilla GNOME OS I've tried to install (besides MATE)

I think what the cause may be is that my touchscreen is broken and it clicks everywhere for me. I'd normally fire up Terminal and disable it with xinput but I can't open terminal.
Any help?

Comment: have you tried pressing F6 when you are starting the cd .. then F6 again and select expert move .. then you can edit the boot options .. not sure what you would use to  kill the touch screen but that may be a start for  you

Comment: @John Orion it didn't really help. I don't see any options when I click f6

Comment: So, I am going to have to ask, what graphics hardware are you running? 

I also have a suggestion, but it's not _really_ a fix, but sort of a combination workaround / diagnostic step, so I am offering it here as a comment instead of an answer. Have you tried adding nomodeset to Ubuntu GNOMEs boot entry and seeing what happens then?

Answer (score 0):

This is an imperfect solution, but blindly navigate your mouse to the shutdown button (This is for the OS, not just the installer), and press the shutdown button, but don't shutdown. just exit the shutdown prompt, and the mouse should reappear.

If this does not work, try pressing the function key that disables/enables the mouse, such as f5.